# Codeigniter email sucess message not print

Tags: codeigniter

Email send successfully , success or error messages not print, here is my code please check [ Controller]

```
if ($this->email->send()){
    $str = "success";
    echo json_encode(array('st' => 0, 'msg' => $str ));
    } else {
    $str = "error";
    echo json_encode(array('st' => 0, 'msg' => $str )); 
}
```

Ajax Script

```
$('#forgot_form').submit(function(){
    $.post($('#forgot_form').attr('action'),$('#forgot_form').serialize(),function(json){
        if ( json.md == 0){
            $('#msg-container').html(json.msg);
        } else {
            ('#msg-container').html(json.msg);
        }
    },'json');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a ajax script error. Just check your modal your return value is not accepting the false condition, and only returning the true value.

Comment: Yes, you are right my ajax code is right , problem is in my modal query , thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this..

`$this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode( (
array('st'
=> 0, 'msg' => $str ));`